# Как создать триггер, который очищает партицию, если она есть, а затем инсертит новые строчки. Или создает ее и инсертит

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Вот такой у меня код:

```
create or replace function partition_users() returns trigger as $$
DECLARE
   i text;
BEGIN
    i = to_char(NEW.dt,'YYYY_MM_DD');
    execute 'create table if not exists users_' || i || '() inherits (users)';
    execute ('delete from users_' || i || ';');
    execute 'INSERT INTO users_' || i || ' VALUES ( ($1).* )' USING NEW;
    return NULL;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;


create trigger partition_users before insert on users for each row execute procedure partition_users();
```

Он, ясное дело, затирает мне все строчки в партициях кроме последней. Как этого избежать?

Comment: *Он, ясное дело, затирает мне все строчки в партициях кроме последней.* Как-то не воспроизводится проблемка-то (да и не должна была)... https://dbfiddle.uk/HXTl9Y7g Ну и не понимаю, почему бы просто не дропнуть партицию и потом создать заново - всё одно её чистить... А на что триггер-то, который юзает сию функцию? часом не на вставочку в эту самую партицию?

Comment: Мне нужно очистить партицию на случай повторной загрузки данных. Я загружаю данные на определенную дату. Под эту дату создается партиция и в нее записываются данные. Если партиция уже есть, нужно ее почистить, а потом загружать данные, чтобы дублей не было. Если я дропну, то этой даты не будет в основной таблице. Триггер выполняется построчно: таблица очищается, добавляется строка, на следующей итерации только что записанная строка стирается

Comment: Дропнуть (если существует, конечно) и **потом создать заново** - уже безусловно, потому что её гарантированно нет. *Если я дропну, то этой даты не будет в основной таблице* - не понял фразы...

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю. Как дропнуть партицию в этой функции? Покажи, пожалуйста, как изменить мой код. Если сделать отдельным триггером, то он почему-то не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- ...
    execute 'drop table if exists users_' || i ;
    execute 'create table users_' || i || '() inherits (users)';
    execute 'INSERT INTO users_' || i || ' VALUES ( ($1).* )' USING NEW;
-- ...
```

PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/rySDXlwO

Comment: доброе утро! Этот код оставляет только последнюю строчку insert`а. А мне нужно создать партицию, допустим, на 10 строк: insert into users
                              with asd as (     select *
     from
  indicators_v
     where dt = '2022-06-10'
     limit 10),
 asd2 as 
     (select *
     from
  indicators_v
     where dt = '2022-04-15'
     limit 10)
select * from asd
union all
select * from asd2;  Так что ситуация та же, что и с delete

Comment: @Elena Ну так делайте per-statement trigger, a не per-row. И соответственно не VALUES, а SELECT FROM INSERTED.

Comment: Я новичок, и видимо что-то делаю неправильно. У меня не получилось реализовать Вашу идею. Решила другим способом, но все равно спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Получилось у меня так:

```
create or replace function partition_users() returns trigger as $$
DECLARE
   i text;
BEGIN
    i = to_char(NEW.dt,'YYYY_MM_DD');
    execute 'create table if not exists users_' || i || '() inherits (users)';
    execute 'INSERT INTO users_' || i || ' VALUES ( ($1).* )' USING NEW;
    execute 'DELETE FROM users_' || i || ' WHERE ctid NOT IN (SELECT max(ctid) FROM users_' || i || ' GROUP BY users_' || i || '.*);';
    return NULL;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```